# having trouble finding phase angle on Pspice

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, pspice, orcad

[image]

The only issues I can see is that my circuit contains a parameter called AC from the AC voltage supply, whereas the one in the example does not ! I don't know how it would work without AC voltage though.

I have used this method of testing for phase angle before, using the total current at the start of the first resistor, and using v+ and V- measurements of the source, in order to compare the two. So I can't see how it is not working this time !

Please if someone could shed some light on this and give me some insights into how to do this is would be very grateful as I have spent a long long time trying to complete this question and others with no avail !

**EDIT**

Here is the information I have been using :

[image]

I have been asked to use time domain (transient) in order to make the analysis, so have been following the instruction to the letter as far as I'm aware, but can't seem to solve the issue, thank you for already explaining that the AC Parameter will not make a difference.

Comment: You'll have to decide if you want to AC sweep that circuit or just measure for one frequency (as intened by the exercise).

Comment: Perhaps those red "0A" are the result of DC analysis, rather than AC analysis? The default DC output from an AC source is often zero volts. Figure out how to start an AC analysis.

Comment: The example says to use a **Run time** of 4 ms, this implies you should perform a **transient** analysis which simulates the circuit over time. The AC parameter is only used for the AC analysis which is a **small signal** analysis which linearizes all the components. In this case that changes nothing as you only have ideal passive components. So you can use an AC analysis as well, sweep for example between 100 Hz and 10 kHz, plot the phase and write down what it is at 1 kHz.

Comment: But the AC parameters **do not** influence the transient simulation at all. Make AC = 100000 V and notice how nothing changes in the transient analysis !

Comment: Thank you for explaining that the AC parameters don't make a difference, i have added more information to the the question to show the instructions that I have been following, I still cant seem to get the expected results

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and got a reasonable result.  One problem though, Pspice ploted the current and the voltage on the same axis.  Since the amplitude of the voltage is 10 and the amplitude of the current is 4mA, the current looks like a flat line.  You can either select the current and multiply it by 1000 or plot it on a separate Y axis.